# Multiplying all the digits of a number in python

Tags: python-3.x

If i have a number 101, i want to multiply all the digits of the number (1*0*1) but this result will become Zero. Instead how to split the number into 10 and 1 and multiply(10*1).

Similar examples,
3003033 -> 300*30*3*3 or
2020049 -> 20*200*4*9

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: So you want to split such that 0s are only ever trailing and not leading?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle yes 0s should always be split on trailing

Answer (score 1):

That's kind of odd, but this code will work:

```
    a = '3003033'
    num = ''
    last_itr = 0
    tot=1

    for i in range(len(a)-1):
        if a[i]=='0' and a[i+1]<='9' and a[i+1]>'0':
            tot*=int(a[last_itr:i+1])
            last_itr=i+1

        elif a[i]>'0' and a[i]<='9' and a[i+1]<='9' and a[i+1]>'0':
            tot*=int(a[i])
            last_itr=i+1


tot*=int(a[last_itr:len(a)])
print(tot)
```

Just put your number at a

Comment: Did you try this for other numbers like 3003033?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a negative look behind to check its not the start of the list and a positive look ahead for nums that are not 0 as your split point.

**REGEX**: Essentially this says split where the next num is not a 0 and it not the start of the line

```
/
(?<!^)(?=[^0])
/
gm
Negative Lookbehind (?<!^)
Assert that the Regex below does not match
^ asserts position at start of a line
Positive Lookahead (?=[^0])
Assert that the Regex below matches
Match a single character not present in the list below [^0]
0 matches the character 0 literally (case sensitive)
```

**CODE**

```py
import re
from functools import reduce

def sum_split_nums(num):
    nums = re.split(r'(?<!^)(?=[^0])', str(num))
    total = reduce((lambda x, y: int(x) * int(y)), nums)
    return " * ".join(nums), total

nums = [3003033, 2020049, 101, 4040]
for num in nums:
    expression, total = sum_split_nums(num)
    print(f"{expression} = {total}")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
300 * 30 * 3 * 3 = 81000
20 * 200 * 4 * 9 = 144000
10 * 1 = 10
40 * 40 = 1600
```

Answer (score 1):

Let `a` and `b` be two integer numbers. Let `c` be a new number made by putting `n` zeros in the right side of `b`. Then multiplying `a` and `c` is equal to multiplying `a` and `b` and `10^n`.

Now you can simplify what you want to do to the following: Multiply digits of your number to each other with the agreement that instead of 0, you will put 10. So actually you don't need to split your number.

Here I defined two functions. In both of them the idea is to convert your number to a string, run a for-loop on its digits and by an `if` condition in the case

1) multiply the previous result to the new digit if it is not 0, otherwise multiply to 10.

```
def multio1(x):
s = str(x)
ans = 1
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] != '0':
        ans *= int(s[i])
    else:
        ans *= 10
return(ans)
```

2) multiply the previous result to the new digit if it is not 0, otherwise add one unit to the number of zeros. Then at the end put as many as number of zeros, zeros at the right side of your final result.

```
def multio2(x):
s = str(x)
ans = 1
number_of_zeros = 0
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] != '0':
        ans *= int(s[i])
    else:
        number_of_zeros += 1
if number_of_zeros != 0:
    ans = str(ans)
    for i in range(number_of_zeros):
        ans += '0'
    ans = int(ans)
return(ans)
```

Now the `multio1(x)` and `multio2(x)` for x=101,3003033,2020049, both gives equal results shown in below.

```
10,81000,144000
```